# Show custom dialog activity via non-activity class

Tags: android, dialog, android-context

I have class below (that is a non-activity class, but it has context), I want to show a custom dialog through one of it's method, I have DialogActivity class as below

**DialogActivity Class**

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnOk;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);

    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_info_ok);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_info_ok:
        this.finish();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

and XML for this layout is as below

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/dialog_message"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_info_ok"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/btn_info_ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show this as another activity when below `onEnabled()` method is executed,

**DeviceAdminReceiverSample**

```
public class DeviceAdminReceiverSample extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
static final String TAG = "DeviceAdminReceiver";

/** Called when this application is approved to be a device administrator. */
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onEnabled(context, intent);
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.device_admin_enabled,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in.setClass(context, DialogActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(in);
}
}
```

but when I call this what it does is, it shows activity as Dialog (as desired), I want to set `info_message` from this class, in the same `onEnabled()` method, how can I do that? If I create method to `setText()` in `DialogActivity()` and call it in that method it throws `NullPointerException`, I don't know how can I get it's reference to set it's message on run time?

The image is below, what it looks like!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the string in the intent in your `onEnabled`

```
in.putExtra("INFO_STR", "My info");
```

Then in your Dialog's `onCreate` you retrieve the string

```
String myInfo = getIntent().getStringExtra("INFO_STR");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent in.setClass(context, DialogActivity.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
in.putExtra("MY_DIALOG_MSG_ID", R.string.info_custom_message);
context.startActivity(in);


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_message);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("MY_DIALOG_MSG_ID", R.string.info_message));
```